# how to prevent download popup when we click on jnlp link from browser because that jnlp is already downloaded and available in my local as shorcut

Tags: jnlp

i have an requirement of opening Swing application through jnlp link from browser.

once click on jnlp link my application will download and installed in our local system,

but again if i go to my browser and click on jnlp link , then also it will ask for download again .

so my problem is if any user clicks again it should not ask for download because it was already installed in my local system.

please do needful , very urgent

regards,
Narasimha

Answer (score 1):

The link on the web page is just a link to `jnlp` resource, that is when clicked you will alway get `jnlp` downloaded to your machine and then executed by Java Web Start module. There is nothing you can do about it.

What you can do is you can add the following lines to your `jnlp`:

```
<information>
   <title>My App</title>
   <shortcut online="false">
     <desktop/>
     <menu submenu="My Corp"/>
   </shortcut>
   <icon href="icon.gif"/>
</information>
```

That will create a nicely branded shortcut on user's desktop that user can click on to start your app instead of going to the web page and downloading `jnlp` file again.